# What is the maximum size of a table name in HSQL DB?

Tags: database, max, hsqldb

What is the maximum character length of object name (e.g. constraint, column, table) in HSQL DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quote from the manual:](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_common_elements)

> The character sequence length of all identifiers must be between 1 and 128 characters.